# Insert Comment - GoogleSpreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to insert comments onto a certain cell once a script has run.
The script I am using is to insert a calendar entry - however I only want it to do this once. To do this, I will get the script to check if a comment/note is entered onto the cell. In theory, this should be easy but I'm having trouble making it select the right cell... Can anyone help? My code is below.

I'm after the comment to go in the cell that corresponds with var = date.
If anyone can give me pointers, I'd really appreciate!

Cheers,
Pete

```
    function CalendarInputIVNShortlist() {`

  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

   var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 26); //What data will be used
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); //Gets the correct calendar

    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var title = row[1];  // Column with Title
      var desc = row[15];       // Column with Next Steps
      var date = row[5];   //Column with Date
       var invite = row[2] //Column with PDC Chairs & IVN Owner
         var sent = row[12] //Check Sent
         sheet.getRange(data[i], 5).setNote(Sent)


    cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date), {description:desc,guests:invite});
var Comment = dataRange(date).setNote("Inputted")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem here:

```
sheet.getRange(data[i], 5)
```

The first parameter you've used, `data[i]`, is an array (that you've already equated to `row` a few lines earlier). The `getRange()` method variance you are looking for expects two Numbers as parameters. If your intent was to add a note to column 5 of the row currently being references in your loop, then you want:

```
sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 5).setNote(sent);
```

Another issue with that particular line is with `Sent`; I assume you wanted to reference the variable you has set equal to `row[12]`, just above, which had a small letter 's' in its name.

Next, there's something wrong here:

```
var Comment = dataRange(date).setNote("Inputted")
```

What is `dataRange()`? Unless it's another function in your script, that returns a Range object relevant to the contents of `row[5]`, I would guess you intended this:

```
sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 5).setNote("Inputted");
```

Comment: okay, you read the code more deeply than I did ;-)... sorry for being too superficial on this one !

Comment: Hi Mogsdad, apologies, I've been on holiday.
That works to put it into my first row, however it isn't working when it should be going further down (I've changed the numRows to 3, to indicate it'll go for my first two rows of data rather than the first).

Is there any advice you can give?

Comment: Mogsdad, kept playing with this and also noticed that it'll insert comments 10 rows apart i.e in row 2, 12, 22 etc when I change the numRow. Can't find any logical explanation in the code for it to skip by 10!

Comment: @user2087338 - Sounds like you worked past your first comment about numRows. About the skipping - look for multiplication (`*`) in `getRange()` methods, because the math works out to `startRow + (i * 10)`. You could post another question with a larger piece of your current code. (i.e. Whole function.)

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.getRange()` needs 2 integers as parameters : the row number and the column number.

In your code you are trying to assign an array (data[i]) as row nuber...this cannot work.

Since it counts from startRow and since array are 0 indexed I would suggest you try like that :

```
sheet.getRange(startRow+i, 5).setNote(Sent)
```